# Photoshop: Varying Levels of Transparency based on Pixel Brightness

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have the image below with the red lightning effect a single layer.  What I'd like to do is make the red  transparent, but maintain pixel brightness, so that I can then overlay it on a red canvas, or blue canvas, etc etc. How can I keep the pixel brightness in this way? Currently, with it all transparent, it looks like this:

http://renx.st0rm.net/test.php?color=FF0000

[image: Baseline Image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you should do is turn the red lightning effect into a layer mask.

1. Create a new layer, fill it with black
2. Add a layer mask to this new layer by either clicking the <kbd>Add layer mask</kbd> button on the Layers pane or using <kbd>Layer > Layer Mask > Reveal All</kbd>
3. Copy your (flattened) lightning artwork to the clipboard
4. Open up the layer mask editor by <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Clicking</kbd> the "Layer mask thumbnail" on the Layers pane. (It's the white box next to right of the "chain").
5. Paste in your copied lightning artwork. It will turn grayscale, and that's okay.
6. Invert the lightning artwork with <kbd>Ctrl | Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>
7. Exit the layer mask editor by clicking another layer on the Layers pane

Following those steps should give you the following result:

[image: Photoshop screenshot]

It's not perfect because your black background in the original image was not `#000000`. We can correct this by adjusting the levels (<kbd>Ctrl | Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>) of the layer mask and setting the white point to the background (the white eyedropper icon).

Doing so gives me the final image below that you can use to overlay on any color:

[image: final image]

Overlaying this on blue would look like this (ignore the text since I don't have the separated layer available):

[image: final image on blue]

[**JSFiddle demo (with bonus animation in Chrome**)](http://jsfiddle.net/mhy2q/1/)

Comment: Nice bonus animation! ;) If you added another 'to {..red..}' would it smoothly transition back to red after blue? It jumps atm and jsfiddle doesn't work well for editing on mobile.

Comment: @Dom improved the animation for you; you can set `animation-direction: alternate` to transition it back